# What is the expectation of the exponential distribution multiplied by indicator function?

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

I am reading research paper [[A New Bayesian Lasso]](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27570577/), where $u$ has the distribution

[image]

The expectation of $u_j$ is given by

$$\frac{1}{\lambda}+|\beta_j|$$.

I know that the term $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ is the expectation of the exponential distribution but where did the term $|\beta_j|$ come from?

I have tried to calculate $$\int _{|\beta_j|}^\infty u_j \lambda \text{Exp}(-\lambda u_j)du_j=\text{Exp}(-\lambda |\beta_j| )\left(\frac{1}{\lambda}+|\beta_j|\right)$$

which gives $\frac{1}{\lambda}+|\beta_j|$ multiplied by $\text{Exp}(-\lambda |\beta_j| )$.

Comment: Notice that $\text{Exp}(-\lambda|\beta_j|) = \mathbb{P}(u_j > |\beta_j| \: | \: \mathbf{y},X,\mathbf{\beta},\lambda)$. So $\frac{1}{\lambda}+|\beta_j|$ would be the conditional expectation of $u_j$ conditioned on $\mathbf{y},X,\mathbf{\beta},\lambda$ and on the event $u_j>|\beta_j|$.

Comment: I think that there is a missing $u_j$ in you distribution, in the $\exp$ term, also a minus at the same spot I would guess. Finally, your pdf doesn't average to $1$, it might be that the distribution is specified to be proportional to what you wrote (modulo the mistake I mentionned before) in which case there is a normalisation factor which is $\prod_j\int_{|\beta_j|}^\infty \exp(-\lambda u_j)\mathbf 1\{u_j > |\beta_j|\}$ (and which therefore removes your unwanted term at the end).

Comment: @P.Quinton, $\text{Exp}(\lambda)$ is just the notation for the exponential distribution just like $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is the notation for the normal distribution so there are no missing terms.

Comment: Except for the normalization then I guess. You still want to have total probability of $1$.

Comment: @P.Quinton, yes I think the normalization term makes sense.

Comment: I would not recommend using such notations when combining distributions, it doesn't make much sense (unless you really know what you are doing).